# Проверить вызов конструктора суперкласса из наследника в нем же

Tags: java, наследование, рефлексия

Есть класс, который наследуется парой других. В них значения переменной `unit` принадлежат другим emun'ам. Необходимо проверить, что конструктор суперкласса вызывается наследником или же нет.

Подскажите, пожалуйста каким образом это можно реализовать?

```
public CellSpec(String unit, String name, Integer index, String type, boolean emptiness) {
        this.index = index;
        this.name = name;
        try {
            this.type = Config.VariableType.valueOf(type);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            this.type=null;
        }

        this.emptiness = emptiness;
        try {
            this.unit = Config.AfdxStructUnit.valueOf(unit);
        }catch (IllegalArgumentException e){

            //**Здесь нужна проверка на вызов конструктора из класса наследника**

            this.unit=null;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если вы в конструкторе родительского класса хотите знать, не вызван ли он из дочернего,  то это указывает на проблемы в дизайне ваших классов.

Вам стоит передавать `unit` не строкой, а enum-ом. Если enum-ов несколько - заставьте их имплементировать общий интерфейс.

В качестве костыля здесь-и-сейчас: дочерние классы могут передавать в конструктор родительского параметр типа `boolean` или `Class`. Но, повторюсь, это плохо и когда-нибудь выстрелит вам в ногу.

Еще можно сделать ваш нынешний конструктор приватным, и обернуть в static-метод, чтобы не позволить потомкам его вызвать. А для потомков сделать отдельный protected-конструктор.

Я имею в виду что-то вроде такого:

```
private CellSpec(String unit, String name, Integer index, String type, boolean emptiness) {
    // ваш текущий код
}

protected CellSpec(String name, Integer index, boolean emptiness) {
  // конструктор для потомков
}

// фабрика для пользователя
public static CellSpec create(String unit, String name, Integer index, String type, boolean emptiness) {
    return new CellSpec(unit, name, index, type, emptiness);
}
```

Но лучше избавиться от всей этой логики с исключениями в конструкторе и то что станет enum-ом передавать как enum.

Comment: Спасибо за совет, пошел читать про имплементацию интерфейса енамами (изначально так и хотел сделать, но не понимал как реализовать). А передаю строкой, потому что данные в конструктор идут из распарсенного XML.

Comment: И, пожалуйста, напишите хоть какую-нибудь реализацию последнего из предложенных Вами способов. Спасибо.

Comment: @I.Perevoz, обновил ответ.